# Object.create( parentObject{ nestedObject:{} } )

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

With reference to [Sam Elsamman's post](http://elsamman.com/?p=32), I'm enquiring if you have written a function which gives the expected behaviour to Object.create() please?

```
var animal = {traits: {}};            // a nested object as parent
var lion = Object.create(animal);
var bird = Object.create(animal);
lion.traits.legs = 4;
bird.traits.legs = 2;

console.log(lion.traits.legs);        // 2

// edited following adiga's comment:`
animal.traits.hasOwnProperty("legs"); // true
```

I expect:

```
// edited following adiga's comment:
console.log(lion.traits.legs);        // 4
animal.traits.hasOwnProperty("legs"); // false
```

Cheers

Comment: `lion` and `bird` share the same `[[Prototype]]`. So, adding a property to `traits` updates the same animal object.

Comment: Are you just after [deep copy of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)?

Comment: Also, why do you expect `lion.hasOwnProperty("legs")` to return true? Even if you did `lion.traits = { legs: 4 }`, it will still return false for `lion.hasOwnProperty("legs")`

Comment: adiga: I was wrong, you're right: it will still return false for lion.hasOwnProperty("legs")

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const create = (proto) => {
  const o = {}
  o.__proto__ = proto
  Object.keys(proto).forEach(key => {
    const val = proto[key]
    if (typeof val === 'object')
       o[key] = Object.assign({}, val)
    else
       o[key] = val
  })
  return o
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var animal = {traits: {}};            // a nested object as parent
var lion = Object.create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animal)));
var bird = Object.create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animal)));
lion.traits.legs = 4;
bird.traits.legs = 2;

console.log(lion.traits.legs);        
lion.hasOwnProperty("legs");         
animal.traits.hasOwnProperty("legs");
```

Comment: @Rich Note that, if there are any functions in `animal`, it will removed by `JSON.stringify()`. I think `lion.traits = { legs: 4 }` is a better option